# Python 3.x: Subtract Same Index from Sequential Lines

Tags: python, list, data-structures, time, iterator

I have data sets of 5000+ lines and varying lengths In terms of elements existing in any given line of data. I have stored each line of data as a `list` where each element is stored as an `index` (i.e. some lines may have 5 indices where others may have 20). Index 2 is **always** the elapsed time for that line of data.

My script currently `iterates` through the data set using a `for` loop as a means to structure the data. See below:

```
f = open(fn)
for line in iter(f):

    remove_blanks = ['']
    entries = line.split()
    ''.join([i for i in entries if i not in remove_blanks])
    trash = (entries[0], entries[1])
    time = int(entries[2])  # Time expressed as elapsed time in milliseconds
    column = [int(v) for v in entries[3:]]
```

Where the lines (from the data set) the script iterates through look something like

`x y #time a b`

`d e #time f g h`

Which are then put into lists like

`['x', 'y', '#time', 'a', 'b']`

`['d', 'e', '#time', 'f', 'g', 'h']`

I would like to iteratively subtract the initial time (non-zero) from the time present in any given line. For example, I would like to do 
`(#time on line x) - (#time on line 0)` and `print` the elapsed time for each line. Perhaps this can be done before the data structure is created, I am not sure.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: So you want to print the value of `(#time on line x) - (#time on line 0)` on every iteration of the loop?

Comment: @jacoblaw Exactly. Additional code I have written analyzes other indices of the lists, but only one list (one line of data) at a time, and then `print`s what I have analyzed. I want the value of `(#time on line x) - (#time on line 0)` `print`ed along with what's `print`ed with each line that is analyzed.

Comment: Take a look at `pandas` or `numpy`.

Comment: @a_guest I have attempted to use `pandas` several times but my permissions on the computer I use have caused several issues. As I am not the administrator, I have not had luck running `pandas`. I am looking for an answer that does not rely on `pandas`, but if that is the only logical method, I will give `pandas` another try.

Comment: @DRauch Have you tried installing locally? `pip install --user pandas` Anyway I can just recommend that instead of putting lots of effort in trying to find a complicated workaround it's much more effective (and eventually pleasant) to get `pandas` to work. It's precisely dedicated to such kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it directly while running the loop:

```
initial_time = None
f = open(fn)
for line in iter(f):

    remove_blanks = ['']
    entries = line.split()
    ''.join([i for i in entries if i not in remove_blanks])
    trash = (entries[0], entries[1])
    time = int(entries[2])  # Time expressed as elapsed time in milliseconds
    # if on first line, initial_time is None, so set it.
    if initial_time is None:
        initial_time = time
    print(time - initial_time)

    column = [int(v) for v in entries[3:]]
```

Also it is perhaps worth pointing out that your line of code

```
''.join([i for i in entries if i not in remove_blanks])
```

is currently not doing anything, because the return value from the `join` method is not being assigned to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
f = open(fn)
t0 = None
for line in iter(f):

    remove_blanks = ['']
    entries = line.split()
    ''.join([i for i in entries if i not in remove_blanks])
    trash = (entries[0], entries[1])
    time = int(entries[2])  # Time expressed as elapsed time in milliseconds
    if t0 is None: # first iteration, store time at t0
        t0 = time
    else:
        print("Elapsed time: {}ms".format(time - t0)) # every iteration except the first, print elapsed time
    column = [int(v) for v in entries[3:]]
```

It will print the elapsed time every iteration. I think this is what you're asking for help with

Answer (score 2):

First off you haven't stored each line as a list. This is just semantics but you seem to have stored your lines in a text file. You're reading lines from a text file, then reading the lines converting them into strings and then splitting them into lists. Remember, semantics are important when programming.

If we're to improve your code as well based on the sample you've provided I would do the following:

```
import time
start = int(time.time() * 1000)
f = open()

for line in iter(f):
    entries = [i for i in line.split() if i]
    print(int(entries[2]) - start)
```

Now, I removed a lot of what seems like cruft for me based on what you actually want to do, which is to calculate a time based on a timestamp.

1. You don't need the list with an empty string to confirm that there's an 
   existing string (be careful of the caveats, see something like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm))
2. You're not storing the return value from the **.join** function, it's completely superfluous
3. **trash** is not used either
4. Neither is **column**

Maybe you're leaving out parts of the code but this is what I could understand from your description. Now, I'm not sure why you want to compare what I call **start** to the the timestamp you have in the manner you do. It will always be a negative value since I presume the file is created prior to the execution of the program, I expect you actually want ***print(start - int(entries[2]))*** but that's just a guess.

If what you're actually looking for is to time your functions I'd recommend to look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html for a start.

Comment: Thank you for the help, cleaned up my script well. I am very new to Python and programming entirely, so I am not surprised my semantics are off. As for the 'column' and 'trash' variables, they are used later in code that I did not provide for simplicity. I am not working with timestamps, but simply values for time i.e.: 4971652 milliseconds.

Comment: @DRauch no problem, I hope you make good progress and keep trying to get better at coding. Few things are as gratifying :)